# Why does visual studio 2008 and SQL Server 2008 get installed when you install SQL Server 2008 R2?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I installed MS SQL Server 2008 R2 and it went ok but also automatically installed was MS SQL Server 2008 and Visual Studio 2008. Can I uninstall them? Or are they for some reason necessary for MS SQL Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think, MS SQL Server 2008 R2 installation automatically  installed VS 2008....Rather, It installs Business Intelligence Development Studio....Business Intelligence Development Studio is Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 with additional project types that are specific to SQL Server business intelligence.